# Git merge remote master to local master after pull request is closed - best practice

Tags: git

What would be best practice to sync local master with remote master ?
When a developer create a local branch, change code, commit, push to remote.
He open pull request for review, the pull request is closed and the remote branch is merged to remote master.
Should the developer merge the local branch to local master, or pull the remote master and forget about the local branch

Comment: The _best_ practice is that you shouldn't even _have_ a local `master`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your question boils down to the process being followed within the team/organization. Pull requested are raised for review by developer. Merging as an activity is owned by different people based on the organization rules. Currently, in my team, QA owns that. They test and merge the feature or bug branch to develop/master branch.

Imagine the amount of work and number of steps required to merge the feature branch in their local machine and update the remote and deleting the local branch (vs) merging it in remote, deleting the feature/bug branch, all with one click of a button.

As a developer I update my remote branches everyday for many reasons but particularly, in this case, if I am creating a new branch from local develop/master, it will be from the new code base.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no new work on the local branch, it should be deleted once it has been merged, after a PR.

If there were new commits done on top of it (pending the PR accepted), those last few commits should be rebased on top of the updated master, in a new branch.